# c# - Changes in cefsharp 79.1.35 (from 75.1.143) creates: 'The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.'

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

I recently update the NuGet package of cefsharp.wpf from 75.1.143 to 79.1.35 and now the following code no longer works:

```
public class Handle
{
    string source = null;
        int loaded = 0;
        private RequestHandler _requestHandler;
        public IWebBrowser _browser;
        public int previousRequestNrWhereLoadingFinished = -1;

        public Handle()
        {
            var settings = new CefSharp.Wpf.CefSettings()
            {
                CachePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "CefSharp\\Cache")
            };

            settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-media-stream", "1");

            Cef.Initialize(settings, performDependencyCheck: true, browserProcessHandler: null);
            _browser = new CefSharp.Wpf.ChromiumWebBrowser();
            _requestHandler = new RequestHandler();
            _browser.RequestHandler = _requestHandler;
        }

        public void OnIsBrowserInitializedChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_browser.IsBrowserInitialized)
            {
                status = 1;
            }
            //status = 0;
        }

        public async void _browser_LoadingStateChanged(object sender, LoadingStateChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!e.IsLoading)
            {
                if (previousRequestNrWhereLoadingFinished < _requestHandler.NrOfCalls)
                {
                    previousRequestNrWhereLoadingFinished = _requestHandler.NrOfCalls;
                    source = await _browser.GetBrowser().MainFrame.GetSourceAsync();
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
...
}
```

The error I get is: "System.InvalidOperationException: 'The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.'"

On the following line:

```
source = await _browser.GetBrowser().MainFrame.GetSourceAsync();
```

I cannot figure out why this happens so far, may you help me out with this issue please?

This is probably related to the changes in the new version, I read them but I could find what exactly broke this.

Thank you for your time and help, it is greatly appreciated.

Update:
As requested in the comments, here is the stack call:

```
This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.VerifyAccess()
System.Windows.DependencyObject.GetValue(System.Windows.DependencyProperty)
CefSharp.Wpf.ChromiumWebBrowser.IsBrowserInitialized.get()
CefSharp.WebBrowserExtensions.ThrowExceptionIfBrowserNotInitialized(CefSharp.IWebBrowser)
CefSharp.Wpf.ChromiumWebBrowser.GetBrowser()
First_4_Figures.MainWindow.Handle._browser_LoadingStateChanged(object, CefSharp.LoadingStateChangedEventArgs) in MainWindow.xaml.cs
```

I will gladly provide additional information if requested.

Comment: you are accessing a non-thread-safe object in an async method. you need to find that object

Comment: Please provide the complete stacktrace (as text, not an image), please make sure it's formatted so it's readable.

Comment: This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
 System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.VerifyAccess()
 System.Windows.DependencyObject.GetValue(System.Windows.DependencyProperty)
 CefSharp.Wpf.ChromiumWebBrowser.IsBrowserInitialized.get()
 CefSharp.WebBrowserExtensions.ThrowExceptionIfBrowserNotInitialized(CefSharp.IWebBrowser)
 CefSharp.Wpf.ChromiumWebBrowser.GetBrowser()
    First_4_Figures.MainWindow.Handle._browser_LoadingStateChanged(object, CefSharp.LoadingStateChangedEventArgs) in MainWindow.xaml.cs

Comment: Edit your question and provide the stack trace as formatted text, it's not readable as a comment.

Comment: I've created issue https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/3032 which will be resolved in the next release.  For now use the Browser property provided by LoadingStateChangedEventArgs. http://cefsharp.github.io/api/79.1.x/html/Properties_T_CefSharp_LoadingStateChangedEventArgs.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until the next bug fix release you can workaround the issue by using the `IBrowser` instance provided by the `LoadingStateChangedEventArgs`. Example below

```
public async void _browser_LoadingStateChanged(object sender, LoadingStateChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.IsLoading)
    {
        if (previousRequestNrWhereLoadingFinished < _requestHandler.NrOfCalls)
        {
            previousRequestNrWhereLoadingFinished = _requestHandler.NrOfCalls;
            source = await e.Browser.MainFrame.GetSourceAsync();
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Issue https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/3032

Comment: This issue is resolved in https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/releases/tag/v79.1.360